# How to refer executable from another directory in CMake?

Tags: build, cmake, code-generation

My project structure:

```
/external-source-generating-tool
/external-source-generating-tool/CMakeLists.txt
/external-source-generating-tool/*.cpp
/src
/src/CMakeLists.txt
/src/*.cpp
/CMakeLists.txt
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_subdirectory(external-source-generating-tool)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

**/src/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT generated-source.cpp
    COMMAND external-source-generating-tool -o generated-source.cpp
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY external-source-generating-tool
    COMMENT "Generating...")

add_executable(my-app source1.cpp generated-source.cpp)
```

The problems is `/src/CMakeLists.txt` cannot find `external-source-generating-tool`:

> Error:Cannot find source file:
>   external-source-generating-tool
>   Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp 
>   .hxx .in .txx

How correctly call `external-source-generating-tool` from `/src/CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: According to error message it seems that you are trying to add `external-source-generating-tool` as **source file** for `add_executable()`. It has nothing common with inability to find `external-source-generating-tool` *executable* for run it.

Comment: Really, it was visible. The problem was with the `MAIN_DEPENDENCY external-source-generating-tool` parameter. I removed it and now all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `MAIN_DEPENDENCY external-source-generating-tool` parameter of `add_custom_command`. I replaced it by `DEPENDS external-source-generating-tool`:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT generated-source.cpp
    COMMAND external-source-generating-tool -o generated-source.cpp
    DEPENDS external-source-generating-tool
    COMMENT "Generating...")
```

And now all works fine.